# How to wrap a contact form with another block?

Tags: 8, blocks, emails

Is there a method to wrap a contact form with another block and make them together a new block or something?

I want to put some information next to the contact form and put them together in a container. Furthermore I want to place other blocks above and under it, so I prefer not to edit in the region twig file.

**Note**: I want to have some text next to my contact form. So it doesn't neccesary have to be a block, but that was the first that came up to me.

Comment: so you want to render a form in block ?? Is it the case ??

Comment: I want to have some text next to my contact form. So it doesn't neccesary have to be a block, but that was the first that came up to me.

Comment: So you can create a simple block and return text and place the block beside the contact block.

Comment: But I won't be able to wrap them together then.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at either of the contributed modules below (quotes are from their project pages).

## Contact Block

> ... provides contact forms in a block. It uses the contact forms that can be created using the Drupal 8 core Contact module.

[image]

**Release info**: only for D8.

## Entityform block

> Allows to load a specified entity form as a block.
>
> Usage: Go to the Block layout admin page (`admin/structure/block`), press Place block in the desired region and select Entity form.

**Release info**: Either for D7, or D8 (but only an alfa release for D8 right now).